# Mapeamento em Fluent API de 1:N cascateado

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Como modelar um relacionamento de **1:N**, onde, **1** usuário pode ter **vários** pedidos, e neste pedido temos referência a outra entidade? Ex:

```
public class Usuario
{
   public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }

   public ICollection<Pedido> Pedidos {get; set;}
}

public class Pedido
{
   public int PedidoId { get; set; }
   public DateTime PedidoDate {get; set;}

   public ICollection<Produto> Produtos {get; set;} 
}

public class Produto
{
   public int ProdutoId {get; set;}
   public string ProdutoNome {get; set;}
}
```

*Obs:* Usando o recurso **Fluent Api** com mapeamentos...

Comment: Não entendi essa parte: **"e neste pedido temos referência a outra entidade?"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há necessidade de usar **Fluent Api** em seu caso, basta adicionar as propriedades de relacionamentos inversa, por exemplo:

```
public class Usuario
{
   public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }

   public ICollection<Pedido> Pedidos {get; set;}
}
public class Pedido
{
   public int PedidoId { get; set; }
   public DateTime PedidoDate {get; set;}

   public int UsuarioId{get;set;

   public Usuario Usuario{get;set;}
   public ICollection<Produto> Produtos {get; set;} 
}
public class Produto
{
   public int ProdutoId {get; set;}
   public string ProdutoNome {get; set;}
   //Se um produto for apenas de um pedido adicione a referência aqui também
   //Se a relação entre produto x pedido for de N:N, crie uma entidade associativa.
}
```

Dessa forma acima você já possui o que deseja. Porém, se realmente quiser fazer por **Fluent Api**, basta fazer assim:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

        modelBuilder.Entity<Pedido>()
                    .HasRequired<Usuario>(s => s.Usuario) 
                    .WithMany(s => s.Pedidos);

}
```